# Is it proper to start a sentence with an Arabic numeral?

Tags: numbers, sentence-starts

For example: 3 monkeys jump on the bed.

Comment: *"1492 is considered to be a significant year in the history of the West, Europe, Christianity, Islam, Judaism, Spain, and the New World"* is not a problem. Some style guides prefer not to write single-digit numerals as numbers rather than words, so might prefer something like *"36 monkeys played with the typewriter.  Three of them hit it with a rock."*

Comment: Duplicate but answers aren’t great: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/464639/191178

Comment: Still a duplicate. [Sentence starting with a number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/464639/sentence-starting-with-a-number) I've edited the original to promote it in the listings.

Answer (score 0):

Here are rules for writing numbers in text: [The Rules for Writing Numbers in English](https://www.scribendi.com/academy/articles/when_to_spell_out_numbers_in_writing.en.html).

Beginning a sentence with Arabic numerals is never advisable (bar exceptions), whatever the size.

*Other references*
[Rules for Writing Numbers and Numerals](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/10-rules-for-writing-numbers-and-numerals/)
[Using Numbers, Writing Lists](http://guidetogrammar.org/grammar/numbers.htm)
[Numbers and Dates](https://nau.edu/writing-style-guide/numbers-dates/)
[Numbers in academic writing](https://aso-resources.une.edu.au/academic-writing/miscellaneous/numbers/)

Comment: -1 for the overly-rigid claim in the second paragraph. It’s matter of style and the like, not correctness.

Comment: @Lawrence Well, that is not, in my opinion, such an error on my part as to deserve so severe a penalty, so much so as the reference uses that very term, but I thank you at least for giving me a motive, which only  few users bother to do.

Comment: You’re welcome; it can be annoying to the poster when downvotes aren’t explained. Leaving aside the bugbear of using “correct” to mean “idiomatic / grammatical / etc”, the larger issue is that starting sentences with numerals isn’t *always* frowned upon. For example, I agree with Henry’s comment that sentences can start with numbers that represent years (“1492 is considered ...”). Even the article you linked to softens their position by referencing consistency and style guides as overriding their ‘rules’.

Comment: ‘Rules’ of English such as those in your linked article are often just generalised observations about the language. It might be more helpful to consider them rules of thumb - good heuristics, but not absolute. Often, they can be broken without breaking the language ... when deeper aspects of communication are satisfied.

Comment: Lots of style guides don't even like you to begin a sentence with a year (MLA says "you should never begin a sentence with a numeral"), recommending spelling out or putting "The year 1492" or other rewriting. Personally I think that's nonsense, but sadly nobody's paid me to write a styleguide. https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/numbers_starting_sentences.htm https://wiki.harvard.edu/confluence/display/HSG/Numbers https://www.una.edu/writingcenter/docs/Writing-Resources/The%20Rules%20Regarding%20the%20Use%20Numerals%20in%20APA%20and%20MLA%20styles.pdf